# Gmail latency due to Firebug: any workarounds short of uninstalling Firebug?

Tags: gmail, firebug

For two months now, I've had increasing latency with gmail:  often 20+ seconds just to load my inbox or return to a previous screen.

I know Firebug can slow down gmail.  I have Firebug 1.4.2.
Despite choosing Firebug's "Disable all panels" and "Off for all web pages" menu commands, I still experience this latency.

Is there anything else I need to be doing?

I'll immediately switch to a different browser.  No gmail latency there.

Comment: Have you tried disabling firebug through the add-ins panel and confirming that this indeed gets rid of the lag? I haven't had any problems with Firebug + Gmail lately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Firefox 3.5.  Seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the same thing with Firebug and other extensions used for web development.

To resolve these issues, I set up a second Firefox profile for web development. This allows me to only install the extensions I absolutley need for everyday browsing in the primary profile. Then, I install all the extensions I use for web development in the second "WebDev" profile.

To run the second "WebDev" profile I set up a second Firefox shortcut with the following command line options:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "WebDev" -no-remote
```

The path is specific to Vista x64, but the other command line options remain the same regardless of platform:

-P "WebDev" = Tells Firefox to start with the "WebDev" profile that I created

-no-remote = This allows Firefox to run different profiles simultaneously when used with the -P option.

Answer (score 2):

Did Gmail gave you a warning? When I try using Firebug on Gmail I get something like this:

[image]

Maybe it's not Firebug's fault?

Comment: Wow. Google *really* knows everything. I was surprised by http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14106, but it knowing you're running Firebug might be even more scary...

Comment: This is where "Fix this" link leades to: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=77355

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I do not notice any real latency and it feels fast, but if I disable it (as a addon, not just in-program / for the site), I do notice that gmail seems to go quicker.

You either use it or don't! The latest version (1.4.2) is a lot better than older versions when set to disabled for sites, but still not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to imply that having Firebug installed also makes it run for each site. On my Mac, Firebug 1.4.x is disabled (grey icon) until I explicitly open it. Then, when switching to another window the icon will still be coloured, but clicking any link on that other site will show the grey icon again. So, it will check the URL, but that *should* be about it.

So: is the Firebug icon coloured in your Firefox?

(Detailed info at [How to enable and disable Firebug 1.4](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/how-to-enable-and-disable-firebug-14/))

Comment: No, it's not colored.